# Snapcraft Placing Default Config Files

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, snapcraft

I am trying to build an application release by using [Snapcraft.io](http://snapcraft.io/), and I have almost all working.
Snapcraft already compiles the source code, generates the .snap file, includes all the dependencies, and so on.
However, I am stuck at how I can initialize some configuration files in the `SNAP_USER_DATA` folder after the first app install.
I do not want to place the files in the default read-only path `SNAP`, as the default parameters should be modified by the user, also I need to generate some additional files, like server certificates.
So I need to copy some files, and also run a script after the first install. 
Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because snaps are installed as root, it's impossible to do exactly as you ask at install time, as `$SNAP_USER_DATA` is user-specific, so it'll always be root's. However, you can do this at install-time using a system-wide directory, such as `$SNAP_DATA`, [using the `install` hook](https://kyrofa.com/posts/snap-install-time-setup-the-install-hook/):

```
$ snapcraft init
Created snap/snapcraft.yaml.
Edit the file to your liking or run `snapcraft` to get started
```

Create the hook. In our case we'll just create a new file in `$SNAP_DATA`, but you could do whatever you wanted.

```
$ mkdir -p snap/hooks
$ echo "touch \$SNAP_DATA/foo" >> snap/hooks/install
$ chmod a+x snap/hooks/install
```

Build the snap.

```
$ snapcraft
Preparing to pull my-part 
Pulling my-part 
Preparing to build my-part 
Building my-part 
Staging my-part 
Priming my-part 
Snapping 'my-snap-name' |                                        
Snapped my-snap-name_0.1_amd64.snap
```

Install the snap. This will run the `install` hook.

```
$ sudo snap install my-snap-name_0.1_amd64.snap --devmode --dangerous
my-snap-name 0.1 installed
```

Notice a file was created in $SNAP_DATA.

```
$ ls /var/snap/my-snap-name/current
foo
```

The only way to get similar functionality for `$SNAP_USER_DATA` would be to wrap your real command in a script that creates the config. This command is then run by the user, which means you get the `$SNAP_USER_DATA` you intend. Of course, this isn't at install-time.